# How to efficiently update a huge amount of data via code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am working on updating a huge amount of data. About 200k of data in the particular table. But I find my code inefficient and slow. Is there a way to optimize this code and make it twice or thrice faster? I am trying to convert their existing password to hashed. I tried linq before but I encounter an "Execution Timeout" issue. Until now I can't find a solution to it. The code below was the one that I am currently using.

```
var hashedProvider = Membership.Providers["HashedProvider"];
if (hashedProvider != null)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration
        .ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT Email from aspnet_membership where IsLockedOut = '0'" +
            " AND IsApproved = '1' And PasswordFormat != '1'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            var UserName = Reader["Email"].ToString();
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                Guid userID = new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                string CurrentPassword = user.GetPassword();
                try
                {
                    UpdateUser(userID, 1);
                    var resetPassword = hashedProvider.ResetPassword(UserName, null);
                    bool Password_Changed = hashedProvider.ChangePassword(
                        UserName, resetPassword, CurrentPassword);
                    if (!Password_Changed)
                    {
                        UpdateUser(userID, 2);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    UpdateUser(userID, 2);
                }
            }
        }
        if (Reader != null)
            Reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Below is the code for `UpdateUser()` method.

```
public static void UpdateUser(Guid userID, int type)
{
    for (Int32 attempt = 1; ;)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration
            .ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string Sql = "UPDATE [aspnet_Membership] SET [PasswordFormat] = @Type where" +
                " UserID = @UserID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to measure this code to understand where is the bootleneck. Then we can start making changes and compare the results

Comment: How slow is it currently? If you're going to execute this entire procedure once for all the existing users and have password hashed automatically for all the future users, is it even worth optimizing? It's working reasonably fast for a single user update, right? Rather than updating users one by one, you could bulk read all of them or a few thousands of them, update their password in a loop, drop the constraints on the table if any, delete the rows of the users you got ready for insertion, and finally bulk insert the rows of the users with the updated password back in the table.

Comment: Also that empty exception catch block in UpdateUser is very dangerous. If there is an error there you could start an infinite loop without even knowing what happened. Remove it and let's see if there are problems there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Steve. About the catch block. There was a  code in there but I did not add it since I think it was unimportant in this scenario. I apologize for the confusion sir.

Comment: @msmolcic I think it would be dangerous if I delete rows and insert a new one back.

Comment: Kit2020 I would suggest to edit your question and remove the try/catch blocks completely, since they are irrelevant to the core issue.

Comment: A thing that you can test to check if it makes any difference is [enabling MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets). This would allow to pass the first opened connection to UpdateUser without opening another connection to the server.

Comment: Using a table valued parameter (TVP) as an input to your stored procedure is going to get you this x2-x3 speed improvement. Use sql type structured in your C# code, then use an enumerator. The code will move blocks of inserts/updates at a time.